# Minimizing conic combination of reciprocals over a polyhedron

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem in $x_1, \ldots, x_m \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{i}{x_i}\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m (m-i)x_i\leq 1\\ & x_i > 0\end{array}$$

One trivial solution is ofcourse setting $x_i=1/(m(m-i))$, which gives an objective  value of

$$m\sum_i i(m-i) \sim m^4$$

Numerical simulations seem to tell me that the answer should be $m^3$ and not $m^4$, but I haven't been able to exhibit a feasible solution.

Can one show that the objective is $\geq m^4$ or give a feasible solution to obtain $m^3$? Since it is not a linear program, I am not sure how to take the dual and analyze it as well.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers should handle this. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: Unfortunately, even using Lagrange multipliers I get an objective value of  $m^4$. I'm assuming the sum $\sum_i \sqrt{i(m-i)}\sim m^2$, maybe this sum is $m^{3/2}$, I'm not sure.

Comment: The $\sum_i \sqrt{i(m-i)} = m \sum_i \sqrt{\frac{i}{m}(1 - \frac{i}{m})} \approx m \int_0^1 \sqrt{x(1-x)} dx \sim m$

Comment: I'm, sorry but by the same logic couldn't I do $\int_0^m \sqrt{i(m-i)} di$ and wolfram says, this is $m^2$. What am I missing?

Comment: $di$ makes all the difference. $\int_0^m \sqrt{i(m-i)} di = m \int_0^m \sqrt{\frac{i}{m}(1-\frac{i}{m})} di = m^2 \int_0^m \sqrt{\frac{i}{m}(1-\frac{i}{m})} \frac{di}{m} = m^2 \int_0^1 \sqrt{t(1-t)} dt$. When you summing, "di" stays put, it is always 1. When you integrating, it scales along with $i$.

Comment: Are your indices correct?  You can make $x_m$ arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 1):

Introducing optimization variable $t > 0$, in epigraph form, the objective to be minimized becomes $t$ and we append the following inequality constraint

$$\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{2}{x_2} + \dots + \frac{m}{x_m} \leq t$$

where $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m > 0$. Using the Schur complement, the inequality above can be rewritten as the following linear matrix inequality (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix} \mbox{diag} \left(x_1, \frac12 x_2, \dots, \frac1m x_m \right) & 1_m\\ 1_m^\top & t\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_{m+1}$$

where the diagonal matrix is positive definite (and, thus, invertible) because $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m > 0$. Hence, the original optimization problem can be rewritten as a (convex) semidefinite program.

Comment: $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m > 0$ would have to be replaced by $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m \geq 0$, however. In semidefinite programs, the inequality constraints are non-strict.

Comment: Why would you do that if using Lagrangian multipliers results in a closed-form solution?

Comment: It would probably be more correct to talk about KKT conditions here, true. But the inequalities $x_i>0$ here are strict and non-problematic, while the other constraint may be changed to an equality constraint without loss of generality since the objective is decreasing in each variable.

Comment: You don't need convexity to get rid of the inequalities. You just need to notice that if you have a point strictly satisfying the inequality, then you can increase any variable until the inequality is satisfied as an equality, and this also simultaneously decreases the objective. So all the minima must lie on the edge of the feasible set. Also, convexity is obvious since the objective is convex on $\mathbb{R}^m_+$

Comment: de Azavedo I don't see how reducing an optimization problem with an obtainable by hand solution to an SDP problem lowers barriers. Besides, this site is not for non-mathematican consumers, but for answers to questions appropriate for the level of the question's creator. And In this case the OP had no problem deriving the exact solution on his own.